# "A" or "an" with "excess"

Tags: nouns

There are two different sentences from Cambridge Dictionary. I'm confused as one of them is written with "a" and the other with "an" Why is that ?

1. A excess of water causes the plant's roots to rot.
2. The new director says there is an excess of staff and that cuts must be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A excess" is a mistake.

The initial sound in "excess" is a vowel  /e/, so the "n" sound is inserted.

Comment: I wonder if it worth noting that one of the features of [Multicultural British English](https://www.robdrummond.co.uk/multicultural-british-english/) (MBE) is article simplification – using ‘a’ for all indefinite articles, regardless of whether the next sound is a vowel, and using ‘thuh’ for all definite articles rather than ‘thee’ before a vowel. There is a BBC Radio 4 continuity announcer who does this, and there are many who would hesitate, for various reasons, to call it 'wrong' in today's UK. I think 'a excess' in the Canbridge entry is a typo or editing error however.

Comment: That's not really relevant to standard English, or English Learning for non-native speakers.  There are lots of dialects and varieties, from doric Scots to Jamaican patois.  Unless the OP is specifically learning MBE, the construction "A excess" is a mistake.  In this dictionary it is probably a typo: literally a mistyping.

Answer (score 0):

correct:  excess

excess /ɪkˈses/ /ˈek.ses/

When a word begins with a vowel sound, we use  before the word.